# sending mutliple attachments in nodemailer depending on request body

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

so far here is the code that i'm working around

```
function sendMail(req,res){  
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:process.env.NODEMAILER_HOST,
    port:process.env.NODEMAILER_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.NODEMAILER_ADDRESS,
      pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASS
    }
  })
     mailOptions = {
      from: req.body.from,
      to: req.body.to,
      cc: req.body.cc,
      bcc: req.body.bcc,
      subject: req.body.subject,
      text: req.body.text,
      html: req.body.html,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: req.body.attachments[0].filename,
          path: req.body.attachments[0].path,
          contentType: req.body.attachments[0].contentType
        },{
          filename: req.body.attachments[1].filename,
          path: req.body.attachments[1].path,
          contentType: req.body.attachments[1].contentType
        }
      ]
    }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json("Failed to Send");
      }else{
        res.status(201).json(req.body);
      }
    });
}
```

and here is my request body

```
{
"from": "example1@gmail.com",
"to": "example2@gmail.com",
"cc": "example3@gmail.com",
"bcc": "test@example.com",
"subject": "Test Request 1",
"text": "Example Text 1",
"html": "<p>Some Paragraph</p>",
"attachments": [
    {
        "filename": "test.doc",
        "path": "dirname/test.doc",
        "contentType": "application/doc"
    },{
        "filename": "test-coverted.pdf",
        "path":  "dirname/test-converted.pdf",
        "contentType": "application/pdf"        
    }
]
```

}

how to loop through attachments without defining it one by one in mail options?

since if i itterate mailOptions then i need to create separate transport which in turns will send different email for different attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting same json object key in your response body, hence you can directly assign the attachments array to attachments key of nodemailer mailOption object. Refer below.

```
function sendMail(req,res){  
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:process.env.NODEMAILER_HOST,
    port:process.env.NODEMAILER_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.NODEMAILER_ADDRESS,
      pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASS
    }
  })
 mailOptions = {
  from: req.body.from,
  to: req.body.to,
  cc: req.body.cc,
  bcc: req.body.bcc,
  subject: req.body.subject,
  text: req.body.text,
  html: req.body.html,
  attachments: req.body.attachments
}
```